# Inserting new field in mongodb deletes other collection attributes

Tags: mongodb

When I insert a new field in my users collection, several of the attributes disappear. Initially, my collection looked like this:

```
{
"_id": "myfi3E4YTf9z6tdgS",
"createdAt": ISODate("2015-03-20T16:25:06.978Z"),
"emails": {
    "address": "abc123@gmail.com",
    "verified": true
},
"profile": {
    "companyName": "Company1",
    "markup": "5",
    "phoneNum": "555-555-5555"
},
"services": {
    "password": {
        "bcrypt": "$2a$10$EsecJJz.PA/qgupHzknYBuGQRW4c6S9hFScc4GesOcO7pixOna1AG"
    },
    "resume": {
        "loginTokens": [
            {
                "when": ISODate("2015-03-23T20:58:48.642Z"),
                "hashedToken": "dlPlzU7KtVhMW1JPDgCQWPYgqIc825ao2bnR84q9NQI="
            }
        ]
    }
},
}
```

I then added an admin flag field by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
db.users.update({_id: 'myfi3E4YTf9z6tdgS'}, {$set: {profile{ admin: true}}
```

I checked the collection's attributes again and found:

```
{
"_id": "myfi3E4YTf9z6tdgS",
"createdAt": ISODate("2015-03-20T16:25:06.978Z"),
"emails": {
    "address": "abc123@gmail.com",
    "verified": true
},
"profile": {
    "admin": true
},
"services": {
    "password": {
        "bcrypt": "$2a$10$EsecJJz.PA/qgupHzknYBuGQRW4c6S9hFScc4GesOcO7pixOna1AG"
    },
    "resume": {
        "loginTokens": [
            {
                "when": ISODate("2015-03-23T20:58:48.642Z"),
                "hashedToken": "dlPlzU7KtVhMW1JPDgCQWPYgqIc825ao2bnR84q9NQI="
            },
            {
                "when": ISODate("2015-03-25T03:32:37.172Z"),
                "hashedToken": "xrojAUw7VwQvbjMtDwaexFEtQprMgl85b+0SY18z58c="
            }
        ]
    }
},
}
```

The profile.companyName, profile.markup, and profile.phoneNum disappeared. Does anyone know what's going on? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dot notation to update individual fields within an embedded object like `profile` instead of replacing the whole embedded object:

```js
db.users.update({_id: 'myfi3E4YTf9z6tdgS'}, {$set: {'profile.admin': true}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use db.users.save() function
The syntax probably looks like

```
db.users.save({_id: 'myfi3E4YTf9z6tdgS', 'profile.admin': true})
```